# Good SMS reader app for Android?

Tags: applications, sms

I'm looking for a good Android application for reading SMS messages.  My requirements are:

- Mark all as read option
- Displaying the number of unread messages on the icon
- Some anti-spam filter (option to block messages from specific phone numbers)
- No ads

Is there such an app?

Answer (score 8):

As things stand Handcent would fulfill all your criteria save the last one. In any case, ads are shown only in the options screen - never in the message list or conversation view.

If you're rooted, you can use AdFree to try to eliminate them.

Comment: I have yet to find an SMS app as complete or that I liked anywhere near as much as Handcent.

Comment: The only niggle is its increasing bloat and "premium" online options, IMHO.

Comment: You can get an advert free version of Handcent, you just have to pay for it.